# Uploading is stuck

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, upload

```js
$("#sendingForm").submit(

        function ()
        {
            if (checkForm())
                sendForm();
            return false;
        }

    );
function sendForm ()
        {
            var formData = new FormData($("#sendingForm"));
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/process.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(response){
                        if (response!="0")
                            errorsDecode(response);
                        else
                            alrightMes();
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
        }
```

I used to serialize form data, but then I had to add file uploading, so i use FormData class. but it doesn't work. I can't find out the reason. Help me please.

Comment: Please add some error message that you are getting either in console or on browser side.

Answer (score 1):

FormData won't unwrap a jQuery object representing the form element.

Try changing:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#sendingForm"));
```

To

```
var formData = new FormData($("#sendingForm")[0]);
```

You also need to prevent processing of the FormData object internally by $.ajax and browser will set the multi-part content type when a  FormData object is used

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/process.php',
  method: 'post',
  contentType: false,// browser will set multi-part when FormData used
  processing: false,
  data: formData,
  success: function(response) {
    if (response != "0")
      errorsDecode(response);
    else
      alrightMes();
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use querySelector instead of $() and I've written contenttype and proccessing but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Need to define "doesn't work" in more specific debugging terms. Start with errors if any in dev tools console. Then open dev tools network tab and inspect actual request and see what is sent, status, response body etc

Comment: Also edit question to show how `sendForm ()` is called

Comment: how to figure them out? I got only page refreshing after submitting.

Comment: I've added a part, where sendForm() is called.

Comment: Try using event.preventDefault() in the submit handler. If checkForm() throws error the `return false` will not be reached and form will submit as default process and reload...which is what you say is happening

Comment: Unfortunately, it still refreshes after submitting

Comment: Alright, it doesn't refresh now, but i've no errors, and nothing supposed to happen happens.